Docker Image Build with Local Packages
I saw some other questions that never answered this question.
I have a NextJs project that I am dockerizing. The projects uses a local dependency, which is a generated api client using the OpenAPI Generator. Due to company tech stack complexities, I can't serve this package from a private repository and just have is locally.
Here is kind of what my project structure looks like:
app/
lib/
  client-fetch/
node_modules/
Dockerfile
package.json
...

Here is what my package.json looks like:
{
  "name": "chatbot-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chat_history_client": "file:lib/client-fetch",

I'm using NextJs's Docker file example but running into some issues:
 [builder 3/4] COPY . .                                                                                                                                  5.5s
 => ERROR [builder 4/4] RUN   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build;   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]  23.7s
------
 > [builder 4/4] RUN   if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn run build;   elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm run build;   elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm run build;   else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1;   fi:
0.579
0.579 > chatbot-ui@0.1.0 build
0.579 > next build
0.579
1.195   ▲ Next.js 14.2.5
1.196   - Environments: .env.local
1.196
1.229    Creating an optimized production build ...
23.35 Failed to compile.
23.35
23.35 ./lib/hooks/use-chat-state.tsx
23.35 Module not found: Can't resolve 'chat_history_client'
23.35
23.35 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
23.35
23.35 ./app/actions.ts
23.35 Module not found: Can't resolve 'chat_history_client'
23.35
23.35 https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
23.35
23.35 Import trace for requested module:
23.35 ./app/api/permissions/[folderId]/route.ts
23.35
23.41
23.41 > Build failed because of webpack errors
23.42 npm notice
23.42 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.7.0 -> 10.8.2
23.42 npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.8.2
23.42 npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@10.8.2
23.42 npm notice
------

So I thought, oh its because the local dependancy isn't in the image when the npm ci happened. so I added the COPY lib/client-fetch ./lib/client-fetch
# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
# Copy local openapi generated dependancy so it can be "npm installed" correctly
COPY lib/client-fetch ./lib/client-fetch
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then corepack enable pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

I still get the same error.
Also worth noting, that I tried a clean install on my local file system, and it worked. However, I noticed in node_modules/ it has the package chat_history_client but as a symlink back to lib/client-fetch/dist/
